# youtube v3 channel list API returns missing channels

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i'm trying to retrieve all channels for a specific user, using the channels list API google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev133-1.20.0:

youTube.channels().list("id,snippet,contentDetails").setMine(true).execute().getItems();
as a response i get ONLY one channel in snippet field with channel ID "xxx"

this user has 2 channels with owner credintials, channel1ID: "xxx", channel2ID: "yyy"
when trying to retrieve the channels for this user using the second channel id:

youTube.channels().list("id,snippet,contentDetails").setId("yyy").execute().getItems()
i get the missing channel in the response.

this user was owner of the channel however i tried changing it to primary owner, still didnt work as expected

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?